# get value_type of dereferencable types

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I how would I achieve the following for any derefernable type?

I find my current solution lacking since I need to do a class template specialization for every type I want it to work with:

```
template<typename T>
struct get_value_type
{
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
};

template<typename E>
struct get_value_type<std::unique_ptr<E>>
{
    typedef typename E::value_type value_type;
};  

template<typename E>
struct get_value_type<std::shared_ptr<E>>
{
    typedef typename E::value_type value_type;
};  

template<typename E>
struct get_value_type<boost::optional<E>>
{
    typedef typename E::value_type value_type;
};
```

I've tried the something along the ways of, which doesn't work.

```
template<typename T, typename IsIndirect = false_type>
get_value_type
{
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;     
}

template<typename T>
struct get_value_type<T, true_type>
{
     typedef decltype(*boost::declval<E>())::value_type value_type; 
};

typedef get_value_type<T, is_indirect<T>::type> value_type;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `std::pointer_traits<PointerType>::element_type` which lives in `<memory>`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template <class Ptr>
struct MyPointer
{
};

template <class Ptr>
struct YourPointer
{
    typedef signed char element_type;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert
    (
        std::is_same
        <
            std::pointer_traits<std::unique_ptr<double>>::element_type,
            double
        >::value,
        ""
    );
    static_assert
    (
        std::is_same
        <
            std::pointer_traits<std::unique_ptr<short[]>>::element_type,
            short
        >::value,
        ""
    );
    static_assert
    (
        std::is_same
        <
            std::pointer_traits<std::shared_ptr<const char>>::element_type,
            const char
        >::value,
        ""
    );
    static_assert
    (
        std::is_same
        <
            std::pointer_traits<boost::optional<int*>>::element_type,
            int*
        >::value,
        ""
    );
    static_assert
    (
        std::is_same
        <
            std::pointer_traits<MyPointer<long long>>::element_type,
            long long
        >::value,
        ""
    );
    static_assert
    (
        std::is_same
        <
            std::pointer_traits<YourPointer<long long>>::element_type,
            signed char
        >::value,
        ""
    );
}
```

20.6.3.1 Pointer traits member types [pointer.traits.types]

> `typedef` *see below* `element_type`;
>
> *Type:* `Ptr::element_type` if such a type exists; otherwise, `T` if `Ptr` is a class template instantiation of the form `SomePointer<T,
>   Args>`, where `Args` is zero or more type arguments; otherwise, the
>   specialization is ill-formed.

Oh, and there's a specialization for pointer types as well:

```
template <class T>
struct pointer_traits<T*>
{
    typedef T*        pointer;
    typedef T         element_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    template <class U> using rebind = U*;

    static pointer pointer_to(see below r) noexcept;
};
```

Comment: Great answer. However, vs2010 doesn't seem to have pointer_traits.

Comment: Sorry to hear about vs2010.  pointer_traits was not introduced until late 2009 by N2982.  Probably missed the deadline for vs2010.  If there is no nested `element_type`, and if `Ptr` is not a class template of the form `SomePointer<T, Args...>`, then use of `pointer_traits` is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

One solution which may be overly broad is to use a template template argument:

```
template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
struct get_value_type<C<T>>
{
    typedef T value_type;
};
```

The more flexible solution would use variadics:

```
template <typename> struct get_first_param;

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename ...Args>
struct get_first_param<C<T, Args...>>
{
    typedef T value_type;
};
```

Comment: How will that work for the case where it isn't a pointer (e.g. the unspecialiazed class template in my example)?

Comment: *non-dereferenceable classes.

Comment: @ronag: You can add this code to your existing code and expand it as you see fit. For instance, you could keep your original primary template, or you could add some trait check for the existence of a `value_type` member type...